# How did Newton know that there is force between two mass?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, mass, history

Newton's Law of Gravitation states:

> $$F=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$

How did he recognize that there is a force between two masses?

Comment: Also [How did Newton discover the universal law of gravitation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139268/how-did-newton-discover-the-universal-law-of-gravitation)

Comment: @Chair "it focuses on the history", as per the [site consensus](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic), means that in principle this should go to [hsm.se], though the presence of pre-HSM duplicates over-rides that.

Answer (score 0):

Sir Isaac Newton spent years studying math, physics and astronomy and eventually he theorized the laws of motion. It is really hard to describe/understand HOW he did it since he was the first in his field. Basically he did like any other scientist do: He made an observation and thereafter he created the model to predict future behaviour of such events. He observed the planets and stars as well as objects on earth behave under influence of a force and then he created a model that fit the observed behaviours.

Comment: "He made an observation and thereafter he created the model to predict future behaviour of such events. He observed the planets and stars as well as objects on earth behave under influence of a force and then he created a model that fit the observed behaviours." I didn't understood this , and what model are you talking about ? Can you tell me the name ?

Comment: @user206414"Newtons first law of motion"

Comment: @User206414 Do not be facitious. Newton created the model of Gravity.