# Derive Gravitational law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, history

How can I derive Newton's gravitational law?

$$F=G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$

Is it impossible to derive?

Did Newton get this just by obervations?

Comment: Is this answers ? :https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139268/

Comment: this was what i was looking for thanks a lot!!

Comment: That’s not Newton’s gravitational law.

Comment: @G.Smith What is Newtons G law?

Comment: $F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$

Comment: @G.Smith Oh thanks i made a typo there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton did not derive this law. He used it to demonstrate Kepler's laws (e.g. elliptical motions of planets), which had been found by Kepler from observations by Tycho Brahe.

Einstein showed how to derive the Newtonian law of gravity from Einstein's equation for gravity